# Json String parse

Tags: json, flutter, parsing

I have a json string getting back from encoding:

```
...","AppPW":"1026"}]} <-
```

and on the end are some undefined characters, sometimes more sometimes less.
how ist the best ay to skip them.

thanks a lot

Comment: You're getting them back from encoding? Is the encoding process something you can control? (Just checking.. don't need to remove them if they're not added in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

this is encoding, i cannot ontrol
On the end sometimer 0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01 or 0x03,0x03,0x03 or 0x03B

```
//================================================================
//
//================================================================
Uint8List aes_cbc_decrypt(Uint8List key, Uint8List iv, String base64String)
{

  Uint8List cipherText=base64.decode(base64String);

  final cbc = CBCBlockCipher(AESFastEngine())
    ..init(false, ParametersWithIV(KeyParameter(key), iv)); // false=decrypt

  final paddedPlainText = Uint8List(cipherText.length); // allocate space

  var offset = 0;
  while (offset < cipherText.length) {
    offset += cbc.processBlock(cipherText, offset, paddedPlainText, offset);
  }
  assert(offset == cipherText.length);

  return paddedPlainText;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found solution
ret= text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[^\x20-\x7E]'), '');